# Style fonts on dropdown select option

Tags: angular

I'd like to create a font-picker list, and style my selection  as per https://codepen.io/visioncan/pen/xLijC based on the item font in the list it represents. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to get it working, I've set the style on  but it does not render with the selected font. Is there anything else I can do to render the items accordingly?

My code

```
fonts = ['Nunito Sans', 'Poppins', 'Avenir Next Medium'];
navbarBrandFont = 'Nunito Sans';

<select [(ngModel)]="navbarBrandFont" class="form-control form-control-lg">
  <option *ngFor="let font of fonts | ssort"
          [attr.selected]="font == navbarBrandFont ? true : null" [ngStyle]="{ 'font-family': font }">{{ font }}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select tag cannot be style the drop-down as it is not customisable you have to create your owns custom using div ul and li

As seen in the link he has not used and select tag.

Here it is the code use

```
<div ng-app="fdApp">
  <div class="font-dropdown" tabindex="1" fd-font-dropdown>
    <span class="label" ng-style="{{'fontslist[selectedIdx].style'}}">{{fontslist[selectedIdx].name}}</span>
  <ul class="dropdown-list">
      <li ng-repeat="font in fontslist" ng-click="changeFont($index)" ng-class="{'sel': $index == selectedIdx}" ng-style="{{font.style}}">
          {{font.name}}
      </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar, not exactly the same. Here is what I did, might help somebody.

In `.ts`

```
fontOptions: { key: string, value: string }[] = [
    { key : 'Arial',value : "font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"},
    { key: 'TimesNewRoman', value: "font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif" },
    { key : 'Georgia',value : "font-family:Georgia, serif"},
    { key : 'Garamond',value : "font-family:Garamond, serif"},
    { key : 'Courier New',value : "font-family:Courier New"},
    { key: 'Verdana', value: "font-family:Verdana, sans-serif" },
    { key : 'Brush Script MT',value : "font-family:Brush Script MT, cursive"},
    { key : 'Copperplate',value : "font-family:Copperplate, Papyrus, fantasy"}
  ];
```

and in `.html`

```
<div class="dropdown dropdown btn-group">
   <button class="btn btn-basiv waves-effect waves-light dropdown-toggle" title="Select Font" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 14px !important; padding: 7px !important; color: rgb(11, 10, 10) !important;">+ Font</button>
   <div class="dropdown-content dropdown-menu">
      <button mat-button *ngFor="let font of fontOptions (click)="changeFont(font.value)"
      [style]="font.value">
      {{font.key}}
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Which results in :
[image]